# Where is the source code for NInject.Framework.Web?

Tags: ninject

I can't find it :(

Comment: Actually I just opened up the DLL in Reflector... its a painfully simple library.

Comment: Please don't downvote this question just because NInject now have a link from their webpage to the source. Back in 2009 they didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ninject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/Framework/Web/

Note that it's Ninject v1

Answer (score 1):

Here is the current 2.0 library [Ninject.Web](http://github.com/idavis/ninject.web)